# Slicing in Python(Not Duplicate, Slicing for Translation)

Tags: python, slice

Hey guys I have a simple question.

How do I slice a string of any length into equal parts

ie AGTTGTCGAGGTTGCGATTTATTGGGTGCGAGT by 3 into

AGT TGT CGA GGT TGC GAT TTA TTG GGT GCG AGT

?

Comment: FYI, in programming jargon slicing would be picking a range and discarding the rest (e.g. "take the third through sixth element"). What you describe is more commonly called splitting.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'AGTTGTCGAGGTTGCGATTTATTGGGTGCGAGT'
>>> n = 3
>>> [s[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(s), n)]
['AGT', 'TGT', 'CGA', 'GGT', 'TGC', 'GAT', 'TTA', 'TTG', 'GGT', 'GCG', 'AGT']
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined`

Comment: Can I do it without forming a list though, I've already done this other way. My problem is I need to translate the sections of 3 into 1 letter chunks next.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: did you seriously just downvote an answer because it was Python 2?

Comment: @DeavenMorris What structure do you want to hold the result in, if not a list? Do you want a generator?

Comment: I need to take user input of length infinity and return it in chuncks of 3.

Comment: @ARS I would like it to be translatable.

Comment: I just need it to recognize that the first 3 letters should be translated to one letter and the next 3 letters should be translated to a different letter etc.

Comment: The question isnt duplicate and I can't find the answer anywhere

Comment: Is it not possible to have python convert string of length 3 into a string of length 1, or do that over an entire list,\.

Comment: @DeavenMorris: That's pretty simple. If you have a list of 3-letter strings and a `dict` of translations, you can use `map(lambda item: translations[item], list_of_three_letter_strings)`. In fact, you can change this answer's list comprehension to a generator comprehension by changing the outer `[` and `]` to `(` and `)` and then it'll work on infinite lists.